# Params hash keys as symbols vs strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
<%= params[:action] %>
```

and

```
<%= params['action'] %>
```

display

```
index
```

but what is the difference between this syntax?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

In Rails, the `params` hash is actually a [`HashWithIndifferentAccess`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/HashWithIndifferentAccess.html) rather than a standard ruby `Hash` object. This allows you to use either strings like `'action'` or symbols like `:action` to access the contents.

You will get the same results regardless of what you use, but keep in mind this only works on `HashWithIndifferentAccess` objects.

Comment: If you need to determine if a parameter is given, be sure to use `params.has_key?` rather than `params.keys.include?` as the former will return correctly for either symbol or strings but the latter will return false for symbols.

Comment: Now the method would just be `params.key?`.

Comment: "same results" but is one better than an another in a stylistic/correctness sense?

Comment: Note that [since Rails 5](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/5_0_release_notes.html#action-pack-notable-changes) `ActionController::Parameters` no longer extends `HashWithIndifferentAccess`, although you can get one by calling [`to_h`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-to_h) or [`to_hash`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-to_hash). (See extensive discussion in [this pull request](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/20868).)