# Why is :key.hash != 'key'.hash in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash, dictionary, rhodes

I'm learning Ruby right now for the [Rhodes](http://rhomobile.com/products/rhodes/) mobile application framework and came across this problem: Rhodes' HTTP client parses JSON responses into Ruby data structures, e.g.

```
puts @params # prints {"body"=>{"results"=>[]}}
```

Since the key "body" is a string here, my first attempt `@params[:body]` failed (is `nil`) and instead it must be `@params['body']`. I find this most unfortunate.

Can somebody explain the rationale why strings and symbols have different hashes, i.e. `:body.hash != 'body'.hash` in this case?

Comment: Well, because they are different objects :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Symbols and strings serve two different purposes.

Strings are your good old familiar friends: mutable and garbage-collectable. Every time you use a string literal or `#to_s` method, a new string is created. You use strings to build HTML markup, output text to screen and whatnot.

Symbols, on the other hand, are different. Each symbol exists only in one instance and it exists always (i.e, it is not garbage-collected). Because of that you should make new symbols very carefully (`String#to_sym` and `:''` literal). These properties make them a good candidate for *naming things*. For example, it's idiomatic to use symbols in macros like `attr_reader :foo`.

If you got your hash from an external source (you deserialized a JSON response, for example) and you want to use symbols to access its elements, then you can either use HashWithIndifferentAccess (as others pointed out), or call helper methods from ActiveSupport:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'

h = {"body"=>{"results"=>[]}}
h.symbolize_keys # => {:body=>{"results"=>[]}}
h.stringify_keys # => {"body"=>{"results"=>[]}}
```

*Note that it'll only touch top level and will not go into child hashes.*

Answer (score 4):

Symbols and Strings are never `==`:

```
:foo == 'foo'  # => false
```

That's a (very reasonable) design decision. After all, they have different classes, methods, one is mutable the other isn't, etc...

Because of that, it is mandatory that they are never `eql?`:

```
:foo.eql? 'foo'  # => false
```

Two objects that are not `eql?` typically don't have the same hash, but even if they did, the Hash lookup uses `hash` *and then* `eql?`. So your question really was "why are symbols and strings not `eql?`".

Rails uses `HashWithIndifferentAccess` that accesses indifferently with strings or symbols.

Comment: This boils down to the same question, why wouldn't they be equal? Aren't they mostly used for the same purpose?

Comment: But aren't symbols only used for named parameters and dictionary keys? If yes, they could as well have the same hash as the respective string. What are other places where symbols are used?

Comment: @AndiDog: I guess, it would bring much more confusion than it would solve problems. Confusion is bad. And your "problem" is easily solvable.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails, the params hash is actually a HashWithIndifferentAccess rather than a standard ruby Hash object. This allows you to use either strings like 'action' or symbols like :action to access the contents.

You will get the same results regardless of what you use, but keep in mind this only works on HashWithIndifferentAccess objects.

Copied from : [Params hash keys as symbols vs strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428318/params-hash-keys-as-symbols-vs-strings)

Comment: You should have posted this link in comments. Copy-pasting posts is bad.

Comment: Actually I just got the comment privilege ... Will take care from next time ... Thanks Sergio