# Stringify/Parse request data through rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm submitting requests on the frontend where I stringify my data (array of objects) and then parse it in the backend.

When I run my specs, I'm getting the error `no implicit conversion of Array into String`

How can I stringify my data in my spec so that it's consistent with what I'm doing in the frontend? Or is there another way where I don't have to stringify/parse my data to handle all of this?

This is how my frontend data structure looks like:

```
"categories_and_years": JSON.stringify(
  [
    {"category_id": 1, "year_ids":[1, 2, 3]},
    {"category_id": 2, "year_ids":[2, 3]},
  ]
)
```

In my controller, I'm validating the data is an array first:

```
  def validate_categories_and_years_array
    @cats_and_yrs = JSON.parse(params[:categories_and_years])
    return unless @cats_and_yrs
    if !@cats_and_yrs.is_a?(Array)
      render_response(:unprocessable_entity, { description_detailed: "categories_and_years must be an array of objects"})
    end
  end
```

In my specs, I'm setting my params like this:

```
context "when all categories and years are valid" do
      let(:params) do
        {
          school_id: school.id,
          id: standard_group.id,
          categories_and_years: [
            { category_id: category_1.id, year_ids: [ year_1.id ] }
          ]
        }
      end
      it "adds standards from specific categories and years to the school" do
        post :add, params: params, as: :json
        expect(school.achievement_standards).to contain_exactly( std_1 )
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

This post explains the difference between a regular ruby hash which you have in your spec and a HashWithIndifferentAccess.

Can you also try to_json?

[Params hash keys as symbols vs strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6428318/params-hash-keys-as-symbols-vs-strings)

```
params = ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new()
params['school_id'] = school.id
params['id'] = standard_group.id
params['categories_and_years'] = [
        { category_id: category_1.id, year_ids: [ year_1.id ] }
]
params = params.to_json

let(:params) { params }
```

Comment: I don't get what your recommendation is. Can you elaborate?

Comment: I'm still getting the same error `no implicit conversion of Array into String`